# How to combine JSON_LENGTH and JSON_EXTRACT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json

Let's say I have a MySQL table like this:

[image]

This table can be created by

```
CREATE TABLE `MyTable` (
`JsonData` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`ExtractedData` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO MyTable (JsonData, ExtractedData)
VALUES ('[10, 20, 30]', NULL);

INSERT INTO MyTable (JsonData, ExtractedData)
VALUES ('["a", "b"]', NULL);

INSERT INTO MyTable (JsonData, ExtractedData)
VALUES ('["q", "w", "e", "r"]', NULL);
```

How can I copy the second last element of json data to `ExtractedData`?

I mean I want to update the table so that it looks like this:

[image]

I've found that `select @len := JSON_LENGTH(JsonData) from MyTable;` is able to get the length of every `JsonData`.

I've also found that `UPDATE MyTable SET ExtractedData = JSON_EXTRACT(JsonData, '$[0]');` is able to copy the first element of `JsonData` to `ExtractedData`.

How can I combine the 2 commands so that I can copy the second last element to `ExtracedData`?

`UPDATE MyTable SET ExtractedData = JSON_EXTRACT(JsonData, '$[@len-2]');` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@len` here is a table. You can't automap it to each update row.

You need to inline the length, e.g.

```
UPDATE MyTable SET ExtractedData = JSON_EXTRACT(JsonData, CONCAT('$[',JSON_LENGTH(JsonData)-1,']'));
```

Check the fiddle at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6PC2CaBxwDdfpruECqAjGR/1

Answer (score 2):

If you use MySQL 8.0, you can extract the second last json item with:

```
JSON_EXTRACT(JsonData, '$[last-1]');
```

As documented here: [11.6 The Json Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html).

Comment: This is good to know but  MySQL 8 is still in RC so probably not  currently a solution for production systems.